# iOS - Objective C, Sort NSArray of NSDictionary(s) via key name

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

How to sort NSArray of dictionaries on the basis of NSDictionary's key name.

lets say, JSON format of NSArray is

```
[
 {
   "keyName" : "C",
   "value"   : "0.1"
 },
 {
   "keyName" : "A",
   "value"   : "1.1"
 },
 {
   "keyName" : "B",
   "value"   : "2.1"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting an array of dictionaries in iOS is very easy simple NSSortDescriptor do the drill.

```
[yourArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"keyName" ascending:YES], nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use    ***sortedArrayUsingComparator***

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
Dictionary *dictoinary1 = (Dictionary*)a;
Dictionary * dictoinary2 = (Dictionary*)b;
return [[dictoinary1 objectForKey:@"keyName"] caseInsensitiveCompare:[dictoinary2 objectForKey:@"keyName"]];
}];
```